# How do I specify my SSH key when connecting to a remote docker server through ssh?

Tags: docker

Generally you can execute remotely using

```
docker  -H ${DOCKER_HOST} ssh://ubuntu@${EC2_INSTANCE} run -it container
```

but how do I specify my ssh key? The equivalent of ssh -i

```
ssh -i ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY} ubuntu@${EC2_INSTANCE}
```

Edit:

```
ssh-add -k ${SSH_KEY_LOCATION}
```

Will work, but is there an equivalent to doing ssh -i ?

Comment: Can you try using either ssh-add, or creating an SSH config at ~/.ssh/config which tells SSH where to find the key?

Comment: @NickODell ssh-add works but I have many keys and don't want to add each one, wondering if there is an equivalent to ssh -i that just uses a key for that command

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I found where this is implemented within Docker, and the SSH url is parsed to get username, host, and port. Nothing else is passed along to the SSH command. (And it is invoking SSH, it's not some kind of native Go client.) https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/8f14db8df2fc9ee5f015df2fa3a3fd1e1d8e0b71/cli/connhelper/connhelper.go#L30